# Unexpected EOF while parsing Python: 2 regex in 1 open file

Tags: python, regex

`file = open(fname, 'r')
codes = re.findall('LIR: (.+)', file.read())
functions = re.findall(';(.+);LIR', file.read())`

Im trying to extract 2 different strings from every 1 line in single file.

It gets 
`SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: its not actually closed as such, it has read to EOF in the first `read()`.

Comment: @cdarke Yeah, it is at the EOF, and it cannot be read further.

Comment: I am not a python expert but:

`file = open(fname, 'r')
codes = re.findall('LIR: (.+)', file.read())
file = open(fname, 'r')
functions = re.findall(';(.+);LIR', file.read())` should do the trick right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I'm being pedantic, but actually it could be read if there was a `seek()` backwards.  But that's not what the OP wants anyway.

Comment: @cdarke Yeah, by "further" I mean "further forward" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time your code calls `file.read()` it is reading the whole file. The second time your code calls it, without first closing the file and reopening it, it is at EOF.

If you want to extract stuff from individual lines of the file then iterate through the file:

```
codes = []
functions = []
with open(fname,'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        codes.extend(re.findall('LIR: (.+)',line))
        functions.extend(re.findall(';(.+);LIR', line))
```

Comment: Wow! That did some trick! Thanks!